# LINQ error with DBNull

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a few null values in my database (wich is correct and normal)

But when I try to use LINQ I get an InvaledCastException: Converion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

How can I resolve this? I don't even get it why it throw that error, when I use a dataview instead o the LINQ, it works perfect.

It's like this:

```
Dim sleutelLinq = dsInventaris.dtSleutel_Compl

sleutelLinq = From sleutels in sleutelLinq WHERE sleutels("tag") LIKE "'% Me.txtTag.Text & "%'" Select sleutels Order By "tag"
```

Comment: Can you please post the LINQ that you are using which causes the error? This is with Linq2Sql?

Comment: What is the actual code that you are using? The code posted won't compile, and it looks like you are trying to use string concatenation to use a value in the LINQ query, in the way that you might use it in a string to use as a SQL query.

Comment: Are you using LINQ2SQL or is it a dataset/datatable with already fetched data?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim sleutelLinq = dsInventaris.dtSleutel_Compl

sleutelLinq = From sleutels In sleutelLinq Where Not IsDbNull(sleutels("tag")) AndAlso sleutels("tag") Like txtTag.Text
```

Or maybe better:

```
sleutels.Where(Function(p) Not IsDbNull(p("tag")) AndAlso p("tag").Contains(txtTag.Text)).Select(Function(p) p("tag"))
```